# Commercial UHF bands in Sweden

Tags: uhf, frequency

I was investigating satellite (onboard) UHF transmitters. Some of them support commercial and amateur bands. To my understanding, amateur bands span between 430 to 440 MHz and commercial UHF between 399 and 403 MHz. Is my understanding correct? Because I have seen some satellite transceivers supporting 390 to 450 MHz. Don't these fall outside the commercial/amateur bands?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

I would like to know if it's possible to transmit at 400 - 403 MHz in Sweden.

Comment: well, your SDR probably also does bands that are neither commercial nor amateur-assigned, you're just not supposed to use them ;) Same for sat transponders.

Comment: What country is this in, Moses? As @webmarc pointed out, it depends on the country of the terrestrial station. Kindly edit your question with a tag, etc. to make this clear.

Comment: The ground station is in Sweden.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the country of the terrestrial station: in the USA, amateur access can be from 420 MHz to 450 MHz depending upon location. I expect commercial bands will also have different regulation & allocation country to country.

Hope this helps!